# Check if some text exists on the webpage using getPageSource. I get error Object has no attribute getPageSource

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to verify some text e.g. "test001" on a webpage using driver.getPageSource in Python, Webdriver.
I get the error object has no attribute 'getPageSource':

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore \TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py", line 32, in test_add_Project
    administration_page.add_project()
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore \Pages\admin.py", line 43, in add_project
    test = self.driver.getPageSource
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getPageSource'
```

Having looked at other people's posts with similar issues.  They replies are to use getPageSource.
I'm not sure why I am getting the error.  Some help appreciated, thanks.

My code snippet is:

```
class AdministrationPage(BasePage):

    def is_project_text_present(self, text):
        #return str(text) in self.driver.getPageSource
        try:
            project_list_test = self.driver.getPageSource
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return "test001" in text # check if the project title text test001 is in the page, return true if it is

class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    try: administration_page.is_text_present("test001")
        except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

Comment: what is `getPageSource`? should it not be `page_source`? I think you are confusing python with java

Comment: I had got it from another post, that must have been Java syntax then.  I have it working now with page_source.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a syntax error to me it should be `page_source` not `getPageSource`. See the [doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html?highlight=page_source#simple-usage)

Try

```
def is_project_text_present(self, text):
        #return str(text) in self.driver.page_source
        try:
            project_list_test = self.driver.page_source
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return "test001" in text # check if the project title text test001 is in the page, return true if it is
```

However, grabbing the full page source to test a **single** text is not a good idea I think. Just find the intended element and test if the element contains the text you are looking for instead

Comment: The post i had took it from had a down vote.  No wonder he had a down vote, wrong syntax.  Your correction is working for me now.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not going to use page source now.  I am trying to use the intended element.  I have tried the following but I get the error TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not WebElement.   My code snippet is def is_project_text_present2(self):
        try:
            text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[contains(text(), "test001")]')
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        #check if the project title text test001 is in the page, return true if it is
        return text in "test001"

Comment: I've got it to work now.  return text.text in "test001"